# Making post specific toggle buttons

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I created a widget in the functions.php which is intended to be added to the services section. I created and displayed 6 unique services using the widget.  In each service, there is a more button which when clicked would toggled the remaining content. The problem now is that whenever I click on a more button of any of the services, all the other services will be toggled. How do can I modify my toggle script so that when a user click on button for service A, only the content for service A would be toggled without affecting others? Below are my codes and screenshot"

//functions.php

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 focus-box" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0.15s over 1s">

        <?php if( !empty($instance['image_uri']) && ($instance['image_uri'] != 'Upload Image') ) { ?>

            <div class="service-icon">

                <?php if( !empty($instance['link']) ) { ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>"><i class="pixeden" style="background:url(<?php echo esc_url($instance['image_uri']); ?>) no-repeat center;width:100%; height:100%;"></i> <!-- FOCUS ICON--></a>

                <?php } ?>

            </div>

        <?php } elseif( !empty($instance['custom_media_id']) ) {

                $zerif_ourfocus_custom_media_id = wp_get_attachment_image_src($instance["custom_media_id"] );
                if( !empty($zerif_ourfocus_custom_media_id) && !empty($zerif_ourfocus_custom_media_id[0]) ) {
                    ?>

                        <div class="service-icon">

                            <?php if( !empty($instance['link']) ) { ?>

                                <a href="<?php echo $instance['link']; ?>"><i class="pixeden" style="background:url(<?php echo esc_url($zerif_ourfocus_custom_media_id[0]); ?>) no-repeat center;width:100%; height:100%;"></i> <!-- FOCUS ICON--></a>

                            <?php } ?>


                        </div>

                    <?php
                }

            }
        ?>

        <div class="focus-right">
        <h3 class="red-border-bottom boxeq"><?php if( !empty($instance['title']) ): echo apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']); endif; ?></h3>
        <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->

        <?php
            if( !empty($instance['text']) ) {
                echo '<p class="boxeq2">';
                    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars_decode(apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['text'])) );
                echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>

         <!-- MORE -->
        <?php
            if( !empty($instance['textmore']) ) {
                echo '<p class="focusmore">';
                    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars_decode(apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['textmore'])) );
                echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>

            <button id="showfocus1" class="btn-services">See More</button>
            <button id="hidefocus1" class="btn-services">See Less</button>

    </div>
    </div>
```

//SCRIPT

```
/* SERVICES TOGGLE*/

;(function ($) {
    function clickHandler3() {
        $('#hidefocus1').toggle();
        $('#showfocus1').toggle();
        $('.focusmore').toggle('slow');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hidefocus1, .focusmore').hide();

        $('#hidefocus1, #showfocus1').on('click', clickHandler3);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: You are probably using ID for more then one time. ID must be unique. With unique IDs you can call that function for target entity.

Comment: @JaxCze How do I create just unique IDs? The widget is just one being replicated so it is not easy for me to use multiple IDs in my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : I have added class to button to show more or less [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jzr03a2f/)

```js
 $('.focusmore').hide();

$('.hidefocus').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).siblings('.showfocus').toggle();
  $(this).siblings('.focusmore').toggle();

});
$('.showfocus').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggle();
  $(this).siblings('.hidefocus').toggle();
  $(this).siblings('.focusmore').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="focus-right">
                <h3 class="red-border-bottom boxeq">widget title</h3>
                <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->

                <p class="boxeq2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in laborum, diam in leo cum nunc. Cursus sollicitudin, nec varius arcu viverra dictumst volutpat tellus. Leo ac tincidunt dolor massa massa in, phasellus amet iaculis, quis pellentesque int</p>
                <!-- MORE -->
                <p class="focusmore" style="display: none;">test tset este tset etesteststestestsdfaf</p>
            <button class="btn-services showfocus" id="showfocus1" style="display: inline-block;">See More</button>
            <button class="btn-services hidefocus" id="hidefocus1" style="display: none;">See Less</button>

        </div>
        <div class="focus-right">
                <h3 class="red-border-bottom boxeq">widget title</h3>
                <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->

                <p class="boxeq2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in laborum, diam in leo cum nunc. Cursus sollicitudin, nec varius arcu viverra dictumst volutpat tellus. Leo ac tincidunt dolor massa massa in, phasellus amet iaculis, quis pellentesque int</p>
                <!-- MORE -->
                <p class="focusmore" style="display: none;">test tset este tset etesteststestestsdfaf</p>
            <button class="btn-services showfocus" id="showfocus1" style="display: inline-block;">See More</button>
            <button class="btn-services hidefocus" id="hidefocus1" style="display: none;">See Less</button>

        </div>
        <div class="focus-right">
                <h3 class="red-border-bottom boxeq">widget title</h3>
                <!-- FOCUS HEADING -->

                <p class="boxeq2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in laborum, diam in leo cum nunc. Cursus sollicitudin, nec varius arcu viverra dictumst volutpat tellus. Leo ac tincidunt dolor massa massa in, phasellus amet iaculis, quis pellentesque int</p>
                <!-- MORE -->
                <p class="focusmore" style="display: none;">test tset este tset etesteststestestsdfaf</p>
            <button class="btn-services showfocus" id="showfocus1" style="display: inline-block;">See More</button>
            <button class="btn-services hidefocus" id="hidefocus1" style="display: none;">See Less</button>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me lots of headache. I have adjusted my codes. The toggle works perfect now. Thanks again